# sed capture group with whitespaces does not work

Tags: sed, yaml

I want to update a tag in a kubernetes kustomization.yaml with sed. the original file looks like this:

```
resources:
  - ../../base
namePrefix: prod-
commonLabels:
  env: production
images:
  - name: my-service
    newTag: current-version
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - deployment.yaml
```

when i use my sed command it just does not work and i'm not sure why:

```
sed -r 'name: my-service\s*(newTag:\s*).*/\1new-version/g' overlays/production/kustomization.yaml
```

as far as i understand this it should match the `newTag` key if it follows a `name: my-service` element. I dont get any errors, it just does not work.

I'm currently testing this on MacOS

Comment: It is advised by experts to use tools like `yq`(which are well aware of yaml files editing) for yaml editing, if you have `yq` installed in your system or you could install it then you could add `yq` tag to get guidance on it IMHO, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RavinderSingh13 comments, `yq` will be an appropriate tool to handle
`yaml` file. If `yq` is available, would you please try:

```
yq -y '(.images[] | select(.name == "my-service") | .newTag) |= "new-version"' yourfile.yaml
```

Output:

```
resources:
- ../../base
namePrefix: prod-
commonLabels:
  env: production
images:
- name: my-service
  newTag: new-version
patchesStrategicMerge:
- deployment.yaml
```

If `yq` is not available and you have a specific reason to use `sed`, then try the alternative:

```
sed -E '
/my-service/{                                   ;# if the line matches "my-service", then execute the block
N                                               ;# append the next line to the pattern space
s/(newTag:[[:space:]]*).*/\1new-version/        ;# replace the value
}                                               ;# end of the block
' yourfile.yaml
```

The reason why your `sed` command does not work is because `sed` is a
line-oriented tool and process the input line by line. Your regex crosses
the lines and will not match.

Comment: your sed command worked. the reason i don't want to use yq is that its not pre installed in my build image and i don't want to create my own.